# I want to change dictionary keys from string to integer

Tags: python, dictionary

The data variable consists integers as keys and another dictionaries as values. However, 0 is in quotes which is considered as string. I want to convert it as an int.

```
data[keys].keys()
dict_keys(['0', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Comment: try this: `data[0] = data['0']` and then `del data['0']`

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to fix your dictionary is to do

```
d[0] = d['0']
del d['0']
```

However, here's a handy function you can use to convert all char int keys to int:

```py
def convert_dict(d):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    for key in keys:
        if isinstance(key, str):
            try:
                int_key = int(key)
                d[int_key] = d[key]
                del d[key]
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return d
```

test

```py
d = {'0':0, 1:1, 2:2, 'hello': 'world'}
convert_dict(d)
{1: 1, 2: 2, 'hello': 'world', 0: 0}
```